# Newer list of open problems in model theory

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, open-problems

In the book *Model Theory* by C. C. Chang and H. J. Keisler, there is a list of open problems in model theory. More exactly, this list is called "Open problems in classical model theory" (on page 597, Appendix B).

> Is there an updated version of this list (new problems added, solved problems marked)?

Are there related lists of open problems in other subfields of mathematics?